# Mounting /var from a CIFS

Tags: boot, samba

Because my sd card recently failed because of large number of writes to /var filesystem I would like to move it to a SAMBA/CIFS.

I tried already and the systems doesn't start at all (it is headless, so I don't know why).
And when I looked at the sdcard /var I can see that RPi recreated all the directories needed and started pushing logs and other data there, instead of the /var that exists on samba.

Are there any other solutions to this? I have few files that change frequently in /var and would like to reduce the wear of sdcard.

Maybe put rootfs on CIFS? (is that possible even?)

Comment: Hello, and welcome to Raspberry PI SE. Beyond that, I only wanted to say two things: 1. I think Dmitry's answer is a good one, and 2. consider the possibility that the RPi may not be the right tool for the job in all cases. There are, for example, some [low-cost SBCs](https://pcengines.ch/apu2.htm) that provide a [mSATA](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Serial_ATA#Mini-SATA_.28mSATA.29) interface which mostly avoids the issue you're having.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Solution #1 would be to buy a big SD card. Decent flash memory withstands at least 300-500 cycles before it starts dying, so with a 64GB card you can write a total of 20TB to your `/var`. That's 50 years if you write 1GB per day.

Solution #2 would be to move `/var` to a RAM disk. This will reduce wear, but you're limited in the amount of data you can store in this way.

Solution #3 would be to put `/var` on a partition located on an external HDD.

Putting `/var` to a network drive is asking for trouble. Don't do it unless you enjoy to debug frequent hard-to-reproduce software crashes.

Comment: #1 - SD cards don't have any wear leveling, so the size of the card doesn't matter
#2 - with only 1GB of RAM and a openhab taking 30% of it I can't do it
#3 - why? There are network loaded rootfs since ages, I know it is not ideal, but considering that SD card performance is at most 2x that of a networked disk in my network I don't see why it would be a problem

Comment: @KrzysztofKrasoń "SD cards don't have any wear leveling" - Any decent brand does, e.g. [SanDisk](https://www.alliedelec.com/m/d/04db416b291011446889dbd6129e2644.pdf) does it since at least 2010 on all microSD products.

Comment: @KrzysztofKrasoń Besides, have you seen [this tutorial](https://www.raspberrypi.org/blog/pi-3-booting-part-ii-ethernet-all-the-awesome/)?

Comment: Oh, I wasn't aware wear leveling exists, I replaced my dead 16 GB cheap card with a smasung Evo plus 32 GB, and hope it won't die soon. As for the tutorial, yes I saw it, unfortunatelly it is only about NFS, and I have NAS with a CIFS/SMB :(

Comment: In my experience, cheap SD cards are a nightmare. I've lost valuable photos and all sorts, and I don't believe it had anything to do with wear leveling - they were just rubbish, almost certainly factory seconds. Unfortunately it's really hard to know what you are buying isn't a fake/second unless you get from a reputable seller.  Amazon and eBay are full of poor quality ones, even ones that say they're not.

Comment: @KrzysztofKrasoń There may be reasons why this tutorial uses NFS. I won't be surprised if you find out that you cannot have your root on CIFS because permission model is different (is there such a thing as CIFS user groups?)